# masksToBounds property of UITableViewCell's content view not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a prototype cell in it. The cell has a content view property which (I assume) refers to the content view which is in the cell by default. I've added a `UIImageView` into this content view (for a background image) and I've set the `clipsToBounds` property of this image view to `true` to make sure it doesn't show past the borders of its parent view. In addition to this, I've also set the `masksToBounds` property of the parent view (the content view of the table view cell) to `true`, which to my knowledge should be hiding its subviews outside the borders. However, if I set the `cornerRadius` of the content view to `45`, the background image view inside the content view is still visible outside the borders. I've triple-checked to make sure all the properties are pointing to the right views and everything seems to be okay, but for some reason the content view of the table view cell doesn't want to mask to its bounds. Does anyone have any experience with this? If so, how do I deal with this?

Comment: Storyboard or code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contentView` of the `UITableViewCell` is also changed internally before being displayed. I recommend you to make `clipsToBounds` in `willDisplayCell` method of the `UITableViewDelegate`, or put the same sized (constrained, autoresized)  `UIView` on top of the `contentView`, setting `contentView.backgroudColor = UIColor.clear`, and moving all `contentView`'s subviews to the view. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Yes! Configuring the content view in the `willDisplayCell` method did the trick for me! Thanks you so much!

Comment: Worked for me, too! Thank you!